# How to get all children recursive in arraylist in Java

Tags: java, recursion

Im working on a Method which should return an Arraylist with all the Descendants. It almost works, but the first ("highest") Person is always included, but I don't need him. Can anyone improve my code? Thanks

getChildren - return only the Children of a Person

```
public ArrayList<Person> getDescendants() {
        ArrayList<Person> descendants = new ArrayList<Person>();
        ArrayList<Person> next = this.getChildren();
        if (next.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < next.size(); i++) {
                ArrayList<Person> b = next.get(i).getDescendants();
                descendants.addAll(b);
                if (!descendants.contains(this)) {
                    descendants.add(this);
                }
            }
            return descendants;
        } else {
            descendants.add(this);
            return descendants;
        }
    }
```

Comment: question is unclear. try to add all code with sample input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems overly complex. Did you mean this?

```
public ArrayList<Person> getDescendants() {
    ArrayList<Person> descendants = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (Person child : this.getChildren()) {
        descendants.add(child);
        descendants.addAll(child.getDescendants());
    }
    return descendants;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
descendants.add(this);
```

You are explicitly adding the parent to your descendants list. Don't do that.

Also note that the `if` statement isn't required. When the length of the list of children is zero, the loop won't iterate at all.